# Yii2. Sending data by ajax in GridVIew isn't works

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, web-frameworks

I want to change status of order in line in GridView, by pushing buttons (check, cross)
[image]

But when I see my $_POST in Controller it has only csrf token, when I make a mistake?

My GridView:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        [
                'attribute' => 'car_id',
                'value' => 'car.state_num'
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'driver_id',
            'value' => 'driver.name'
        ],
        'status',
        'first_date',
        'second_date'

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
        'template' => "{confirm} {decline}",
            'buttons' => [
                'confirm' => function ($url, $model, $key='new_stat') {
                    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>', $url, [
                        'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'confirm'),
                        'data-confirm' => Yii::t('yii', 'Сдать авто?'),
                        'data-method' => 'post',
                        'data-pjax' => 1,
                    ]);
                },
                'decline' => function ($url, $model, $key='new_stat') {
                    return Html::a('<span style="color: red" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>', $url, [
                        'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'decline'),
                        'data-confirm' => Yii::t('yii', 'Отказ?'),
                        'data-method' => 'post',
                        'data-pjax' => 2    ,
                    ]);
                }
            ],
            'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
                if ($action === 'confirm') {
                    $url ='contracts';
                    return $url;
                }
                if ($action === 'decline') {
                    $url ='contracts';
                    return $url;
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
]); ?>
```

And my Controller:

```
public function actionContracts()
{

    if(Yii::$app->request->post())
    {
        print_r($_POST);
        die();
    }

}
```

Why it does not send data? When i push the button it has only:

> Array ( [_csrf] =>
>   P-VomWJo5fwNwRi8uGnoMrw-uJPvLK9TM-k4k_Ka5SVQvF_VDR6Cj3unc_6BD6B-2Xf-27ln1RJHik32uf6RQA==
>   )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What data are you trying to send? And how are you trying to send it, I cannot see that in the code sample you sent.

You can add parameters to the request adding them to the `data-params` attribute of your link.

For example:

```
'template' => "{confirm} {decline}",
'buttons' => [
  'confirm' => function ($url, $model, $key='new_stat') {
    return Html::a(
      '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>', 
      $url, [
        'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'confirm'),
        'data-confirm' => Yii::t('yii', 'Сдать авто?'),
        'data-method' => 'post',
        'data-pjax' => 0,
        'data-params' => [
          'param_name_1' => 'param_value_1',
          'param_name_2' => 'param_value_2',
          'param_name_3' => 'param_value_3',
      ],
  ]);
  },
  'decline' => function ($url, $model, $key='new_stat') {
    return Html::a(
      '<span style="color: red" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>', 
      $url, [
        'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'decline'),
        'data-confirm' => Yii::t('yii', 'Отказ?'),
        'data-method' => 'post',
        'data-pjax' => 0    ,
        'params' => [
          'param_name_1' => 'param_value_1',
          'param_name_2' => 'param_value_2',
          'param_name_3' => 'param_value_3',
      ],
    ]);
  }
],
```

Those parameters will be sent as `POST` parameters.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I want to sent post parameters to my controller 'Contracts'. But this way (your example) isn't works when i try to catch POST parameters in controller it has only csrf token.
I have a list of contracts and I wan to change status of it from GridView (Accept or decline)